# setuptools: file dynamic_dynamodb.py (for module dynamic_dynamodb) not found

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm trying to build my fairly simple Python project so that:

- A system wide command `dynamic-dynamodb` is installed
- That command points to `dynamic_dynamodb.main:main`

My project looks like this:

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── MANIFEST.in
├── Makefile
├── README -> README.md
├── README.md
├── dynamic_dynamodb
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── dynamic_dynamodb.py
│   └── main.py
├── example-dynamic-dynamodb.conf
├── requirements.txt
└── setup.py
```

I got it to work fine when I just had one Python file in the root folder. But when the project grew I had to split the code and put it into a module (i.e. the folder `dynamic_dynamodb`). Now my `setup.py` looks like this:

```
""" Setup script for PyPI """
from setuptools import setup, find_packages


setup(name='dynamic-dynamodb',
    version='0.3.0-SNAPSHOT',
    license='Apache License, Version 2.0',
    description='Automatic provisioning for AWS DynamoDB tables',
    author='Sebastian Dahlgren',
    author_email='sebastian.dahlgren@gmail.com',
    url='http://sebdah.github.com/dynamic-dynamodb/',
    keywords="dynamodb aws provisioning amazon web services",
    platforms=['Any'],
    py_modules=['dynamic_dynamodb'],
    packages=find_packages('dynamic_dynamodb'),
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
    install_requires=[
        'boto >= 2.6.0'
    ],
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 4 - Beta',
        'Environment :: Console',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License',
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
        'Programming Language :: Python'
    ],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'dynamic-dynamodb = dynamic_dynamodb.main:main',
        ]
    }
)
```

The problem is that when I build with `python setup.py sdist` I see the following error:

```
file dynamic_dynamodb.py (for module dynamic_dynamodb) not found
```

Does anyone have any pointers to kick me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue by following this guide: http://wiki.python.org/moin/Distutils/Tutorial

The springing points being:

- Create a new script in the root directory (this will be the script that is site-wide accessible)
- No need to use `py_modules` in `setup.py`. Just use packages.
- Now using `distutils` because I don't need any `setuptools` features

My new `setup.py`:

```
""" Setup script for PyPI """
from distutils.core import setup


setup(name='dynamic-dynamodb',
    version='0.3.0-SNAPSHOT',
    license='Apache License, Version 2.0',
    description='Automatic provisioning for AWS DynamoDB tables',
    author='Sebastian Dahlgren',
    author_email='sebastian.dahlgren@gmail.com',
    url='http://sebdah.github.com/dynamic-dynamodb/',
    keywords="dynamodb aws provisioning amazon web services",
    platforms=['Any'],
    packages=['dynamic_dynamodb'],
    scripts=['dynamic-dynamodb'],
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
    install_requires=[
        'boto >= 2.6.0'
    ],
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 4 - Beta',
        'Environment :: Console',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License',
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
        'Programming Language :: Python'
    ]
)
```